# DotNet EF tools version downgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-core-6.0

I have installed dot net in my Mac and by mistake I updated the dotnet EF tools to the latest version (7.0.0). I need to revert back to the previous version (6.0.11).

As far as I read it, it was suggested to uninstall and reinstall with required version. Since I am new to this, I find it a bit confusing on should only EF tools be uninstalled or the whole dotnet. I have very little idea on that

Comment: What's wrong with the [official MS documentation on the dotnet ef tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) ? It clearly says: *Install a specific version by appending --version <VERSION> to your command* - there's your answer right there ....

Comment: As stated earlier "by mistake I updated to latest version" I tried already. It says "The requested version 6.0.11 is lower than existing version 7.0.0.". Thus I'm not able to downgrade

Answer (score 12):

To uninstall:

```
dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef --global
```

To install version specific:

```
dotnet tool update dotnet-ef --version 6.0.8 --global
```